# BIGQUERY - bq load could not parse

Tags: google-bigquery

Recently I started to work with BigQuery in my company. We use AWS Redshift database, so I made an UNLOAD to S3 with **PIPE** as **field delimiter**, after I sent to GCS with gsutil.

So I started to load into BQ, but in some tables this doesn't work. See the log:

```
bq load 
--project_id=movile-di
--field_delimiter="|" 
--schema=mte.json
--allow_quoted_newlines=true 
--allow_jagged_rows=true 
--ignore_unknown_values=true 
--max_bad_records=100 
corp.mte_201301 

gs://movile-di/telecom/atlas/dynamic/2013/01/mte/* Waiting on
> bqjob_r333c660745fe8874_00000156c36e9a5e_1 ... (0s) Current status:
> DONE    

BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job
> 'movile-di:bqjob_r333c660745fe8874_00000156c36e9a5e_1': Too many
> errors encountered. Failure details:
> - gs://movile-di/telecom/atlas/dynamic/2013/01/mte/mte.csv.0000.gz: Could 
not parse '2500","key":"MOV_PK_MOVILE_ATLASSENDMESSAGE"}' as int
> for field billing_share_content_partner_share (position 17) starting
> at location 1596

> - gs://movile-di/telecom/atlas/dynamic/2013/01/mte/mte.csv.0000.gz: Could 
not parse '100001","key":"MOV_PK_MOVILE_ATLASSENDMESSAGE"}' as
> int for field billing_share_content_partner_share (position 17)
> starting at location 2060

> - gs://movile-di/telecom/atlas/dynamic/2013/01/mte/mte.csv.0000.gz: Could 
not parse '-","key":"MOV_PK_MOVILE_ATLASSENDMESSAGE"}' as int
> for field billing_share_content_partner_share (position 17) starting
> at location 2929

> - gs://movile-di/telecom/atlas/dynamic/2013/01/mte/mte.csv.0000.gz: Could 
not parse '-","key":"MOV_PK_MOVILE_ATLASSENDMESSAGE"}' as int
> for field billing_share_content_partner_share (position 17) starting
> at location 4413

> - gs://movile-di/telecom/atlas/dynamic/2013/01/mte/mte.csv.0000.gz: Could 
not parse '-","key":"MOV_PK_MOVILE_ATLASSENDMESSAGE"}' as int
> for field billing_share_content_partner_share (position 17) starting
> at location 5289
```

In this table I have an field as JSON. I guess that **bq load** doesn't understand the field_delimiter and gave me an error.

Could anybody help me? I tried everything that I know, but still doesn't work.

Comment: What did you, specifically, end up doing to solve the "could not parse....as int" issue? It looks like "find and replace '-' with nothing" would solve the last three errors.  However what did you do to solve the first two errors?

Comment: Could you provide a sample csv and json schema file so I could try to replicate the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try loading your file(s) as if it is CSV with just one field
For this you should pick field delimiter such that it is for sure not present anywhere else in file
After load is done you have power of BigQuery (Legacy or Standard SQL Mode) to parse it the way you need within BigQuery. Of course it can depend on your actual schema – but in many cases it helped!
Take a look at [JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions) and [UDF for Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) and [Scalar UDF for Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions) as those are most useful "tools" for parsing in such cases

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued to try and replicate your issue, I don't have AWS but figured I'd just try a round trip in BigQuery:

First I create a table with a json data type:

```
create or replace table pmo.TableWithJson(UserKey INT64, Client JSON) as
select 111 as UserKey, JSON '{"ClientKey": 10, "Name": "Tesla", "Address" : "Alameda"}' as Client
union all
select 112 as UserKey, JSON '{"ClientKey": 11, "Name": "JLL", "Address" : "Sydney"}' as Client
union all
select 113 as UserKey, JSON '{"ClientKey": 12, "Name": "Prosper", "Address" : "SF"}'  as Client;
```

Next I exported that file a zipped file in GCS bucket:

```
bq extract --compression=GZIP --destination_format=CSV --field_delimiter="|" --print_header=true pmo.TableWithJson gs://bucket/pmo/FileWithJson.csv.gzip
```

File looks like this:

```
UserKey|Client
111|"{""Address"":""Alameda"",""ClientKey"":10,""Name"":""Tesla""}"
112|"{""Address"":""Sydney"",""ClientKey"":11,""Name"":""JLL""}"
113|"{""Address"":""SF"",""ClientKey"":12,""Name"":""Prosper""}"
```

I then defined a schema file:

```
[ {"name": "UserKey", "type": "INTEGER"},
  {"name": "Client", "type": "JSON"}
]
```

I then imported the file to a new table:

```
bq load --replace --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --field_delimiter="|" pmo.NewTableWithJson gs://bucket/pmo/FileWithJson.csv.gzip ./FileSchema.json
```

The new table looks exactly like the original one.

Compare the above to what you have... at a guess i would say that your json is formatted differently to above or your schema definition isn't defined correctly. Would be a pain to have to load all the rows into a single column and then parse them.